# Can we get a stronger GUI indication of a change in Input Source?

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I often switch input sources to type in different languages' alphabets.

Because the same key is used to switch to each new input source, it is hard to remember the state of the system. Of course I can look at the toolbar, but that is just a small indicator.

Can we get a stronger indication, like a change in the color of the toolbar and dock, as input sources change?

Comment: Your best recourse is to send [Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html) to Apple with your idea. I did a little research, and there doesn't seem to be a macOS specific way to do this. Perhaps some developer can come up with a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to not use the "same" key to switch each new input source.  Instead you can try the [Kawa](https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa) app, which lets you give each layout its own keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Brilliant! Not only does having different shortcuts make the difference clearer as you type, but  Kawa can show a banner notification when you switch, again making it clearer. The one thing is doesn't do is give a completely different GUI theme depending on keyboard :-) but this goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

In the input source menu bar tab, there is an option to show the input source name, which should make it a lot easier to see.

[image: Menu bar with input source name]

Additionally, holding down the keyboard shortcut for "Select the previous input source" (not "Select the next source in Input menu"!) shows a menu that allows you to cycle through all of your input sources:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I already have the name there. But in typing, I would rather not look up and read some small text.

Comment: ״holding down the keyboard shortcut." Please clarify. Holding down the globe/Fn key on the building keyboard does nothing, not even show the keyboard-switching popup. (For this, I need to click and release.) Holding down ⌃-Space (which is the "Select previous Input Source" shortcut according to Preferences) does show the pop-up, but does not cycle.

Comment: As I said in my original answer, this doesn't work with the normal "select the next source in input menu", it has to be done with the "select the previous input source", which you have already figured out. Holding down space with whichever modifier keys you have selected makes the menu pop up. You can then release the spacebar and the popup will remain there as long as you are holding down the modifier keys. You can then press space repeatedly to cycle through the input options. However, I don't think you'll find this helpful due to the small delay.